# Bad Request When Using PostAsJsonAsync C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to Post a model to my MongoDB, but my Blazor app's post command does not even reach my API's Post method in the Controller. I've seen some topics about this and also tried to debug this issue for hours.

I am trying to post a really simple model.

```
public string MomentCategoryName { get; set; }
```

The button click activates this method. (I hardcoded a CategoryName for this one.)

```
public async Task PostAsync(MomentCategoryModel momentCategory)
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await _api.ApiClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/MomentCategory/Create", momentCategory))
            {
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
            }
        }
```

The baseuri and the client is initialized in another class, but the whole uri will look like this: `https://localhost:7141/api/MomentCategory/Create`

The `PostMomentCategory` in the `MomentCategoryController` gets a `MomentCategoryModel` from another library:

```
[BsonId]
[BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.ObjectId)]
public string Id { get; set; }
public string MomentCategoryName { get; set; }
```

And then in the  this code should run, but the compiler never gets to this, it never runs:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Create")]
public void PostMomentCategory(MomentCategoryModel model)
{
    _momentCategoryData.CreateMomentCategory(model);
}
```

Because of that I get back a Bad Request. But when I do a GET request that almost the same, it runs correctly. Example:

```
public async Task<List<MomentCategoryModel>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await _api.ApiClient.GetAsync("api/MomentCategory/GetAll"))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<MomentCategoryModel>>();
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
            }
        }
```

Thank you for your help and your time in advance!

Comment: Can you post your entire `MomentCategoryModel` model? Also, have you tried invoking the endpoint from Postman to see if it is running correctly there?

Comment: @RahulSharma Right now these are the full `MomentCategoryModels`. If I use the `[FromForm]` in the `PostMomentCategory` method, the POST is successful from Postman. But if I use my program, it still doesn't hit the breakpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `MomentCategoryController` I adjusted the Post method as the following:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Create")]
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
public void PostMomentCategory([FromForm] TestMCategoryModel model)
{
    _momentCategoryData.CreateMomentCategory(model);
}
```

In `public async Task PostAsync(MomentCategoryModel momentCategory)` method I added a list of KeyValuePair with one element. And also added an HttpContent like this: `HttpContent httpcontet = new FormUrlEncodedContent();`

This way it works, I get an OK code back (Status code 200). Maybe it would work with the suggested string content if I adjust what the API should consume. I will do a test with that as well, but right now it works this way.

I would like to thank everyone who took the time to read thru the issue and suggest a possible solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can try `PostAsync` method to `POST` your `Model` to your api endpoint. You can do this:

```
public async Task PostAsync(MomentCategoryModel momentCategory)
{
    string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(momentCategory);
    StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await _api.ApiClient.PostAsync("api/MomentCategory/Create", content))
    {
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

And in your API method, you need to add `[FromBody]` attribute to get your posted data:

```
public void PostMomentCategory([FromBody]MomentCategoryModel model)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Meanwhile I tried this one as well, but didn't work. Even tho I was able to resolve the issue. I will post it as an answer soon. But I do appreciate the suggestion and the time!

Answer (score 0):

For the json post you need a frombody option

```
public void PostMomentCategory([FromBody] MomentCategoryModel model)
```

Comment: Or flag controller as api controller by adding [ApiController] on class

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. The [ApiController] is added by default and I also tried the [FromBody] before creating this topic, but it is not working. When I'm debugging, in the Controller I don't even hit the breakpoint. Any other ideas? I'm open to anything to solve this issue. 
Thank you again for taking the time to answer the question, really appreciate it!